# Regular expression, to get text after blank space

Tags: java, regex

I have this text:

```
1 A Maths
```

And i would like to get only Maths.

I don´t know about regular expressions.

Can any one help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of asking for a fish, learn to fish. That's what programmers do.

Comment: Why would you need regex for this? If you don't know about regular expressions, what is it that lead you to believe your problem is solved with them? Seriously, this question has no information on what it is you're really trying to do, other than saying that you want to get "Maths" from a string.

Comment: Your question is vague. If your string is always "1 A Maths", the easiest solution is to take the substring from char 4. Somehow I don't think that's what you want?

Comment: @Mike I need it for using it in Android for getting a variable with the name of the subject and pass it to another Activity

Comment: @Boschman No of course, it´s variable, although always is a number, a blank space, a letter, a blank space and the number of the subject

Comment: If you were only allowed to use functions you already knew, what would you do?

Comment: string indexOf(" ") space, find the third iteration of that, then grab the substring from there to the end of the string

Comment: To get everything after the **last** whitespace character of a string: use `/\s(\S+)$/` ([example](http://regex101.com/r/fJ9pJ7))

Comment: @SamSullivan I would like to vote for you

Comment: @user3229208 keep in mind that if there is a trailing space after the name, it will break the regex

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you split the string ?

```
String chain="A Maths";
String[] array=chain.split(" ");
String number=array[0];
String course=array[1];
```

...
[How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Indeed this is the best solution, I don't know why they wanted REGEX, it's not the optimal solution in this case.